# Installed Kubuntu alongside Windows 10, now can't access internet on Windows 10

Tags: internet

So I am a newbie and this is my first time attempting to install Kubuntu. Everything went decently okay, but now when I login to Windows, I cannot access the internet. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: As long as you manage to boot Windows, it's *fairly* unlikely that Kubuntu is the problem here. Ubuntu does not modify Windows in any way, except to make space for installation, and modify boot loader.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But, it would be a prety big coincidence if it wasn't due to Kubuntu. I have never had a problem in the 3+ years of owning this laptop, but as soon as I install Kubuntu, I now cannot access internet when I login using Windows. I did get some weird error messages at the end of installing Kubuntu, right when I was at the end of the installation and it was restarting, but I'm not sure if that has anything to do with it. I've waited hours, and I still cannot access the internet with Windows, but have no issues when logging in with Kubuntu.

Comment: It's fundamentally a Windows issue, and I would suggest asking at [Superuser SE](https://superuser.com/), as Windows is on topic there. They simply have more knowledge about Windows, and are better able to help.

Comment: Did you disable fast startup in windows?

Comment: Yes i did disable fast startup on Windows. It did not help.

Comment: can you access internet on kubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

check the date and time of your windows OS, linux changes the time if you dual boot. rarely mismatch is time results in internet problems.

Comment: I changed the time and date to be correct, and it still will not connect to the internet.